# scipy/numpy equivalent of c++ eigen3 example

Tags: python, scipy, linear-algebra, eigen3

In scipy there is an ldl decomposition and a solve method, But I am not able to get the same result in python as I get using eigen3 for a very simple piece of code.
Here is the C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
using namespace std;
using namespace Eigen;
int main()
{
   Matrix2f A, b;
   A << 2, -1, -1, 3;
   b << 1, 2, 3, 1;
   cout << "Here is the matrix A:\n" << A << endl;
   cout << "Here is the right hand side b:\n" << b << endl;
   Matrix2f x = A.ldlt().solve(b);
   cout << "The solution is:\n" << x << endl;
}
```

The output of the program is:

```
Here is the matrix A:
 2 -1
-1  3
Here is the right hand side b:
1 2
3 1
The solution is:
1.2 1.4
1.4 0.8
```

How can that be written using numpy/scipy to get the same result?

I tried some of the following things:

```
import scipy.linalg

A = np.array([[2,-1],[-1,3]])
b = np.array([[1,2],[3,1]])
a = scipy.linalg.ldl(A)
print(scipy.linalg.solve(a[0],b))
```

I tried transposing and doing various combinations of members of a and b. I get a result but its just not the same as in the C++ program, so what am I doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: Stack overflow isn't a free code conversion service. At least show what you tried and where you are stuck with it.

Comment: I tried doing: `A = np.array([[2,-1],[-1,3]])`  `b = np.array([[1,2],[3,1]])`  `a = scipy.linalg.ldl(A)` `scipy.linalg.solve(a[0],b)`. I tried transposing and doing various combinations of members of a and b

Comment: Add additional information into your question please, not in comments.

Comment: Note that for very small matrices (perhaps up to 4x4, but this may depend on other things) it is often worth to explicitly calculate the inverse, instead of computing a decomposition and solving linear systems. But probably, the 2x2 example was just for illustration.

Answer (score 0):

Ahhh I got confused by all wording.
Its just solving Ax=b. 
So `scipy.linalg.solve(A,b)` does the trick.

Comment: This is probably inefficient, if you want to solve other linear equations with the same `A` later.